# evalf(Int) works quite strangely for me

Tags: maple

```
evalf(Int(-(1/9)*exp(-n*(cos(phi)+sin(phi)))*cos(n*sin(phi))*cos(n*cos(phi))*n*(60*n+7*exp(2*n)-7*exp(-2*n))/(Pi^2*(exp(2*n)-exp(-2*n)+4*n)), [phi = 0 .. (1/2)*Pi, n = 0 .. inf]))
```

is leaving all the integral signs in result. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to spell out the word `infinity`.

Comment: Formal acceptance of my Answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Didnt even know it exists, sorry.